# How to Interpret HTML + XML without XHTML declaration

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, xhtml, frames

What is the type of this document.I am confused as it has html 4.0 declaration and also contains xml.
Here is the structure of the document:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Frameset//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <TITLE>Container</TITLE>
        <LINK href="css/xyz.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <frameset >
        <FRAMESET rows="97%,28" border="0" frameBorder="0">
            <frame name="main" src="ContainerInner.htm">
            <FRAME  Name="Statusbar" SRC="html/MainStatusbar.htm">
        </FRAMESET>
        <noframes>
            <p>This page requires frames, but your browser does not support them.</p>
        </noframes>
    </frameset>
</html>


<!-- ContainerInner.htm -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>ContainerInner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <IFRAME  Name="MainScreen" SRC="html/loading.htm"></IFRAME>
    <IFRAME Name="MenuTree" SRC="html/BlankMenu.htm" />
    <iframe name="ToolbarScreen1" src="html/FavouriteMenus.htm"></iframe>
    <IFRAME name="TaskQueues" src="html\UserInfo.htm"></IFRAME>
</body>
</html>

<!-- html/loading.htm -->
<!-- screen inside IFRAME MainScreen  -->
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <HTML>
            <HEAD></HEAD>
            <BODY> </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have following questions:

1. Is it an XHTML document or HTML.
2. Is it legal to have multiple doctype declarations like above.
3. Will latest version of modern browsers like chrome support this document as it has frames.

Comment: what is this type of document with html inside xml called?

Comment: Those are three documents. Which one are you asking about? Also, we can't tell what kind of documents they are without seeing the MIME types. And is the name `ContainerInner.html` supposed to be the same as `ContainerInner.htm`? And without checkjing, I couldn't say what the different browsers do when trying to display an XSLT stylesheet in an iframe.

Comment: To qualify, if the middle document is HTML (MIME type `text/html`), it will display two iframes; the two bottom onbes will be contained in the second one and will not be shown. If it is XHTML (`application/xhtml+xml`), there will be an error since the DOCTYPE is flawed. And it doesn't have a namespace. And the browser won't know what to do with the uppercase IFRAMEs.

Comment: The above code runs in IE 5,6,7,8,9 and in quirks mode in 10 and 11.